# Data at the root level is invalid

Tags: xml, soap, coldfusion

Having a major headache while trying to call a webservice. (Search Server Express)
The error is: Data at the root level is invalid

```
    <cfoutput>
    <cfsavecontent variable="xmlBody">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">      
        <soap:Body>
            <Query xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search">
                <queryXml>xml</queryXml>
            </Query>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cfhttp url="http://server_name/_vti_bin/Search.asmx" method="POST" result="httpResponse">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Host" value="server_name"/>
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="text/xml; charset=utf-8"/> 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-length" value="#len(trim(xmlBody))#"/>
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPAction" value="urn:Microsoft.Search/Query"/>

    <cfhttpparam type="xml" value="#trim(xmlBody)#" />
    </cfhttp>
    </cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that it is perhaps expecting a root level node and you having your data at the root level is invalid.

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">      
        <soap:Body>
            <Query xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search">
                <queryXml>xml</queryXml>
            </Query>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
</root>
```

Comment: Now I am getting this: Envelope namespace was unexpected. Expecting http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/

Comment: Try removing one or all of the xmlns: namespaces on the Envelope line, hard to know without seeing what else it's expecting.